# Install mediapipe on pydroid3

Tags: python-3.x, mediapipe, pydroid

I'm working on a hand tracking project on Android phone using pydroid3. But I'm not able to install mediapipe on it. It says no matching distribution found. Kindly help if it's possible to install it.

Comment: did you try building by your own? [refer link](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows )